# Open program before login - SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, windows, startup

I have an SQL Server in my garage where I have a worker which stores some information from a website every 4 hours. I want the program to open automatically so I added the .exe file to the directory `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

My problem is that when the system reboots I have to remotely connect to the server and login before the application will start. How do I make the program run before windows login? I've read about Services, but I'm very confused about what I'm suppose to do. The program is a simple vb.net application with a minimal UI consisting of a Notification Icon in the taskbar - if that matters.

Comment: If you want to do service - create windows service application, and `onStart` event, which will occur when computer booted under condition that you set your service automatic. So on this event just run your exe. Once you compile service you can install it either via `installutil.exe` (.net framework) or `sc.exe` (windows).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931(v=ws.11).aspx), there is an option for "On boot", "on logon", "on certain date" etc. to run any kind of task